# Applicability of UnitOfWork for Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

Does it really require a pattern for transaction management in Entity Framework ? Because I see all these are built right into Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'Unit of work' pattern if you wish, generally with the repository pattern but it is perfectly fine to use transactions with Entity Framework.

```
 using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                //transactional work here
            }
```

[MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx)